# How to assign specific properties from one object to another

Tags: javascript

Let's say i have these two Objects.

```
let object1 = {
    a: 'value1',
    b: 'value2',
    c: 'value3',
    d: 'value4',
    e: 'value5'
}

let object2 = {
    a: 'value6',
    b: 'value7',
    c: 'value8',
    d: 'value9',
    e: 'value10'
}
```

I want to assign values of `c, d and e` properties of object2 to object1. Only these properties, not all, so object1 to be

```
let object1 = {
    a: 'value1',
    b: 'value2',
    c: 'value8',
    d: 'value9',
    e: 'value10'
}
```

I know that i can do it this way

```
object1.c = object2.c;
object1.d = object2.d;
object1.e = object2.e;
```

but i want to know if there is a more elegant way with fewer lines of code. Some objects may have over 10 properties, and need to assing only 7-8 of them. 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of `object1.c` you can write `object1['c']` which means you can put the properties in an array and iterate over them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and then `Object.assign()`

```js
let object1 = { a: 'value1', b: 'value2', c: 'value3', d: 'value4', e: 'value5'};
let object2 = { a: 'value6', b: 'value7', c: 'value8', d: 'value9', e: 'value10'};

let {c, d, e} = object2;
Object.assign(object1, {c, d, e});

console.log(object1);
```